# I have a series of times, I want to loop through each time and retrieve the elapsed time from the next time to the time reported in the row before

Tags: python, loops, datetime, while-loop

I have a df with a series of datetimes:

```
                     time     timezone   temperature (C)   
0     2023-03-29 13:54:38   GMT +01:00         23.242188              
1     2023-03-29 14:14:38   GMT +01:00         23.539062              
2     2023-03-29 14:34:38   GMT +01:00         23.492188              
3     2023-03-29 14:54:38   GMT +01:00         23.429688             
4     2023-03-29 15:14:38   GMT +01:00         23.914062
```

the times are expected to come at 15m intervals. How do i loop through so that I can display the elapsed time in an additional column named 'elapsed' based on the next time. So the time in row 1 should calculate the time elapsed since the time in row 0, then the time in row 2 should calculate the time elapsed since the time in row 1, the time in row 3 should calculate the time elapsed since the date time in row 2 and to keep going until the end of the df.how can i increase the index for iloc? I tried setting the start and end variables and increment them in the while loop but it resets on every loop so I get the same time elapsed values for each row.

The aim is for me to identify when each date time takes more than 15 minutes since the last recorded time.

Could i get some help please using the most simplistic way?

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("temps.csv") df = pd.DataFrame(data) temp_time = pd.to_datetime(data["time"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

date_a = 0 
date_b = 1 
i = 0 
while i < len(df):
    start_dt = temp_time.iloc[date_a] 
    next_dt = temp_time.iloc[date_b] 
    df['elapsed'] = next_dt - start_dt 
    date_a += 1 
    date_b += 1 
    i += 1 
    print(df)
```

Comment: `df['elapsed'] = df['time'].diff()` ?

Comment: Thanks! Worked a charm! I had used this previously but i misinterpreted the results and so i thought it didn't work. Thanks for making me revisit it again.